# Auto filling tables in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I'm working on an Excel Spreadsheet and I'm trying to set it up to auto populate a single table from multiple other tables. What I mean by that is I have table1, table2, table3, and table4. All of these tables will have the same column headers. I want to be able to type data into table 2-4 and have it auto fill up table1. I'm not sure if that is something that is possible for me to do. I'd prefer to avoid using any macros if possible but if necessary I can use them. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not able to post comment on your question yet. I wanna ask about the condition of your auto fill.

If there's no condition, i think you can simply use "=" then. example: the data is in table 2 cell A1, then put **='table 2'!A1** into table 1 cell A1.
note: table 1 dan table 2 is assumed as sheet name.

But if it's in the same sheet, then you only type =[cell name], like **=A1**

Comment: So the way I want to set it up is I have maybe 10 sheets in 1 work book. I want to be able to type in the tables I have created on 9 of them and have it auto fill the table on the 10th sheet. There can be upwards of 100-200 rows in each of the 9 sheets we will be typing in.

Table 1-10 contains column name, date, score
I want to type in tables 1-9 and have it automatically fill in table 10's columns up to 1000+ rows.

Comment: yes... as I've said above, you can insert this formula `='[sheet name]'![cell name of first sheet]` to the cell of your 2nd sheet and so on. here's the sample [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c7qyNLoC3zxgTqCfmlB6HoRwBwHmjB6Q057BLNYj6Z0/edit?usp=sharing). If you insert data in sheet "source", the autofill will applied to sheet "autofill". You can change the formula as you needed and paste it to other sheets as well.